# are nilpotent matrix unitary equivalent to its Jordan normal form?

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $A$ be a n by n complex matrix, which is nilpoent, so $A^{n}=0$. Since the eigenvalue is degenerate, for $v\in ker(A)$, we can orthogonalize vectors in $ker(A)$. Similarly for $ker(A^{2}),...,ker(A^{n})$. Under this circumstance, can we make the transformation matrix $P$(where $P^{-1}AP=A'$) unitary by choosing orthonormal generalized eigenvectors of $A$?

Comment: In jordan form: a nilpotent matrix of rank one has Frobenius norm of $1$.  Yet there are many rank one nilpotent matrices with Frobenius norm $\neq 1$. So this can't be true in general.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try $n=3, Ae_1=e_2,A^2e_1=Ae_2=e_2+e_3, A^3e_1=A(e_2+e_3)=0$.

The orthogonal complement of $\ker(A^2)$ is 1-dimensional so there is no freedom, the first column of $P$ must be $we_1$ and the others will be $wA e_1,wA^2e_1$, for some $w\in \Bbb{C},|w|=1$.

But $A e_1$ is not orthogonal to $A^2e_1$.